# Права или привилегии?

Tags: дефект, локализация, нет-в-transifex, привилегии

На [странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics), которая пока ещё недоступна, написано:

> [image: расширенные]

Требуется согласовать "права" и "привилегии". А так же использовать правильные кавычки «ёлочки» и вынести точку из-под них.

На transifex строки с кавычками не существует в явном виде, т.е. она склеивается как минимум их двух, а кавычки вероятно жестко закодированы.

Comment: Компромисс: правилегии